# Why have I stopped being able to access a website from an ip that is allowed in htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, ip, ip-address, http-status-code-403

I have been using this code for a while in .htaccess:

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
```

Everything worked fine and I was able to access from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx, while others could not access and got a 403 error.

A few days ago, though, I started getting the 403 error when accessing via my laptop from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx. The strange thing is that when I access from my mobile phone, using the same IP, everything works fine.

If I delete the contents of .htaccess, then my laptop can access the website, but add the contents again and then it can't.

I am pretty sure the code in .htaccess is correct, since it worked before. 
I get the ip I am using by googling "what is my ip". Is there another IP I should be using?

I had some problems with FileZilla that same day and may have made some changes related to that... but I can't remember doing anything that I didn't undo.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: Maybe your laptop is using IPv6 now.

Comment: Wow, thank you @OlafDietsche ! That was it. I've been scratching my head for days trying to fix this thing. I have no idea what IPv6 does, but I unchecked it in properties for the wifi and restarted the computer. And now everything is back to normal. Amazing. Thanks again!! If you put this as an answer, I'll mark it as the correct one (have no idea how this thing works, if you get points for the correct answer..).

Comment: Ok, googled ipv6. Everything makes sense now :) It's a different form of IP so the xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx form doesn't work.

Comment: It was just a wild guess, but I'm glad it works again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes a client accesses a server through [IPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6), which is the most recent Internet protocol and successor to IPv4.
IPv6 has a different kind of [IP addresses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address), and therefore Apache doesn't recognize your laptop anymore.

To enable your laptop via IPv6 as well, you may give an appropriate IPv6 address to [`Allow`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_access_compat.html#allow), e.g.

```
Allow from 2001:db8::a00:20ff:fea7:ccea
```

This may be given in addition to the IPv4 address, so you may connect either way.